# How do I get rid of activities bar at bottom of screen?

Tags: taskbar

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.   I did the same thing on my computer at work and this problem did NOT appear.

See attached photo to know what I'm talking about.  I'm not talking abuot the title bar on top with activities, current open software, today's date, buttons for settings and volume and internet and reboot.

I'm not talking about the favorites bar, which the system has moved to a different monitor than the one it's set to appear on.

In place of it on the primary monitor, is this dark gray bar where EVERYTHING I have open is displayed in BLACK.

I tried right clicking on it to delete it and no context menu appears.  At far right is 1/2 which refers to workspaces - I'm only using one workspace.  I have three monitors.  Don't need multiple workspaces.

I've attached a screenshot to know what I'm talking about.

How do I get rid of it?

Well it won't let me add an image just link to an image that's already onn linne, sooI 'll also be posting where I can post an image..   And  your  software is creating the double letters

Comment: no screenshot attached. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.